# Why can't I access objects through the window object when using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-object

I'm trying to access a function through the window object. In my code, my function gets referred to by a string so I have to use the window object (or eval) to grab it. I tested out my code in pure JavaScript and it works perfectly. But when using jQuery it fails. Here is my test code:

```
function speak(words, callback){
  for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
      console.log(words);
  }
  if(callback)
    callback.call();
}

console.log(window['speak']);​
```

[Here is a link to the pure JavaScript version which works.](http://jsfiddle.net/X9YQz/)
[Here is a link to the jQuery version which doesn't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/qCnjB/)

**What do I need to do to make this work in jQuery?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't declare `speak` as a member of `window`, and JSFiddle actually wraps it in a `document.ready` callback. [You'll need to explicitly set `window.speak = speak` as part of your code if you want it available on the `window` object](http://jsfiddle.net/qCnjB/1/).

Alternatively, you need to configure your fiddle to [execute without a wrapper rather than `onDomReady`](http://jsfiddle.net/qCnjB/2/)

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm. So any function not in a `document.ready` callback is automatically declared as a member of window, but if it is in a `document.ready` then it is not?

Comment: @Aust, functions and variables declared in the global scope are implicitly added to the global object, functions and variables declared within another function persist only within the function. When writing JavaScript, it's advisable to write all code within a closure, so as to avoid accidental global pollution.